# With an xs:any element can I define the attributes of the any elements?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I want to be able to allow the following in my XSD but am stumped. I understand that I could use xs:any in a structure like this but this does not allow me define attributes for the elements that occur.

```
<xs:element name="parent">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I would like to be able to have a defined parent and then have any element as a child but the children must have attributes specified by the following.

```
<xs:attribute name="attribute1" type="xs:string" use="required" />
<xs:attribute name="attribute2" type="xs:string"  />
<xs:attribute name="attribute3" type="xs:string" use="required" />
```

So I guess what I'm really asking is can I define the attributes for an any element? Below is the structure I want to acheive. Where the child elements of parent can take any name but must have the attributes as specified above. Thanks!

```
<parent>
    <AnyElementName1 attribute1="val1" attribute2="val2" attribute3="val3"/>
    <AnyElementName2 attribute1="val1" attribute2="val2" attribute3="val3"/>
    <AnyElementName3 attribute1="val1" attribute3="val3"/>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With xs:any you can constrain the namespace of the elements, and you use processContents="strict" to require that the element is one that's declared in the schema, but you can't constrain the elements to be of a particular type. Perhaps rather than using xs:any you should use xs:element naming an abstract element declaration, one whose type defines the required attributes, and then make all the permitted elements members of the substitution group of this abstract element.